# Simple API call within the context of DocFx preprocessor

Tags: ecmascript-5, preprocessor, docfx

I would like to know if it is possible to make a simple API call (e.g. GitHub API v3) within the context of a DocFx custom template preprocessor.  I have been trying all sorts of different approaches, but nothing has fully worked so far.

My goal is to make a call to an API to retrieve some data, and then update the model accordingly to be used in the *.liquid or *.tmpl renderers.

I have tried using the **http**/**https** node modules.  I have also tried using **node-fetch**.  It results in a docfx build error something like:

> Error:Error transforming model ".../index.raw.json" generated from
>   ".../index.md" using "conceptual.html.primary.js". Error running
>   Transform function inside template preprocessor

According to DocFx documentation, preprocessors follow the ES 5.1 standard.  My code conforms to this.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

By the way, I am able to do simple model manipulation just fine, so I understand the basic concepts here with the DocFx preprocessors.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benefit of others, I discovered DocFX uses **jint** which cannot require a Node library directly.  Therefore, it appears the plugin route is a better way to go for this use case.